# Efficiently use Dense layers in parallel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I need to implement a layer in Tensorflow for a dataset of size N where each sample has a set of M independent features (each feature is represented by a tensor of dimension L). I want to train M dense layers in parallel, then concatenate the outputted tensors.

I could implement a layer using for loop as below:

```
class MyParallelDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, dense_kwargs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dense_kwargs = dense_kwargs
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.N, self.M, self.L = input_shape
        self.list_dense_layers = [tf.keras.layers.Dense(**self.dense_kwargs) for a_m in range(self.M)]
        super().build(input_shape)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        parallel_output = [self.list_dense_layers[i](inputs[:, i]) for i in range(self.M)]
        return tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(parallel_output)
```

But the for loop in the 'call' function makes my layer extremely slow.
Is there a faster way to do this layer?

Comment: What is the value of M? And how do you even know that the for loop makes things slow? Also please define slow, with numbers.

Comment: M is around 200 and during prediction it takes more than 2 seconds (my model has only this layer and a simple dense output layer).

Comment: Well what do you think 200 extra layers will do? You added 200 times computation of a dense layer, it will be slower than not having 200 layers.

Comment: SO do you know how to implement that without the for loop?

Comment: The for loop is not the problem, the added computation is. You could just reduce the value of M to increase performance.

Comment: Well even if the for loop is not the problem I would be happy to learn how to avoid using for loop in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be doable using `einsum`. Expand this layer to your liking with activation functions and whatnot.

```
class ParallelDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super().build(input_shape)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=[input_shape[1], input_shape[2], self.units])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.einsum("bml, mlk -> bmk", inputs, self.kernel)
```

Test it:

```
b = 16  # batch size
m = 200
l = 4  # no. of input features per m
k = 10  # no. of output features per m

layer = ParallelDense(k)
inp = tf.random.normal([b, m, l])

print(layer(inp).shape)
```

> (16, 200, 10)